# Single digit month and day format specifier in Gnuplot 5.2

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot 5.2 and would like to use single-digit months and days (1-12 and 1-31). There are different format specifiers for zero padded hours (`%k`, `%H`, `%l`, and `%I`), but there doesn't appear to be equivalents for months and days.

Is there a modified format specifier or workaround to get single-digit months or days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
### single digit day and month
reset session

set xrange [0:3600*24*60]
set format x "%01d.%01m.%Y" time
plot x

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I confirmed this works, but can you help me further understand why this works? From a quick test, it looks like the leading 0 is not required. By adding a min-width specifier, does GnuPlot shift into a different mode that removes leading zeros by default?